# Can't click on label inside list item

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, rating

When clicking on a label inside a list item and radio button list, the selectedIndexChanged event doesn't work, even though the radiobuttonlist is not disabled.

This is the code:

```
<asp:Label ID="rank" runat="server" class="starss"> 
  <asp:RadioButtonList OnSelectedIndexChanged ="SaveRating" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="star-rating" ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem id="star1" Value=1 runat="server" ><Label for="star1" title="1 stars" ><i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></Label></asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem id="star2" Value=2 runat="server" ><Label for="star2" title="2 stars" ><i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></Label></asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem id="star3" Value=3 runat="server" ><Label for="star3" title="3 stars" ><i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></Label></asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem id="star4" Value=4 runat="server" ><Label for="star4" title="4 stars" ><i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></Label></asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem id="star5" Value=5 runat="server" ><Label for="star5" title="5 stars" ><i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></Label></asp:ListItem> 
  </asp:RadioButtonList> 
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: Share your code in the question itself . Images are not readable.

Comment: sorry but this is my first time, "program doesn't work"  i mean this OnSelectedIndexChanged ="SaveRating" was not working

Comment: By "Not working", you mean the selectedIndexChaged event doesn't fire? Or there's a problem occurring when it does? Have you tried moving the button list outside the label, just in case that's interfering? I'm not sure why you'd want the whole list inside a single label like that. I don't know if that would cause a problem, but it's just worth trying - or changing the label to a Panel or something.

Comment: Check the renderd html, my bet is your radio button id does not match what you are using in the labels.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need or want your custom label element. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3se8ewc.aspx):

> When the RadioButton control renders to the browser, it does so in two
>   parts: an **input** element that represents the radio button, and a
>   separate **label** element that represents the caption for the radio
>   button. The combination of the two elements is wrapped in a **span**
>   element.